# Yii2. Better ways to apply maxSize validator to a certain file extension?

Tags: yii2

One of my model's field called `file` must be validated as following:

1. it needs to be a file
2. it should only be of following extensions: txt, png, jpg, jpeg, gif.
3. if it's a txt file, its size shouldn't exceed 100 KB.

While it is easy to implement the first and the second rule, implementing the third is implicit. I wrote a general rule inside the `rules` method, that makes sure it is a file, and it is of one of the allowed extensions:

```
        [
            ['file'],

            'file',
            'extensions' => ['txt', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
            'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false,
        ],
```

Then, I wrote this inside my model's `saveFile` method, which is invoked when the file needs to be saved (i.e. it is called after calling the `validate` method):

```
        if ($this->file->getExtension() === 'txt') {
            $tempModel = DynamicModel::validateData(['file'], [
                [['file'], 'file', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 100],
            ]);

            $tempModel->file = $this->file;

            if (!$tempModel->validate()) {
                // putting the error to the main model
                // so it can be shown
                $this->addErrors($tempModel->getErrors());

                return false;
            }

            $this->file->saveAs($this->pathToNewFile());
        }
```

Although it works, the code seems to be quite heavy so I wonder if there's any better ways to do that, thanks!

P.S. [here](https://pastebin.com/yLM99fqA) is the full code of my model, and [here](https://pastebin.com/A6DkJZ8P) is the code of my controller in case you need it.

Comment: You could write a custom validation rule and take inspiration from yii\validators\FileValidator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the functionality of the third rule, in rules() you can put:

```
[['file'], 'file', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 100, 'when'=>function($model){
return $model->file->extension == 'txt';}]
```

To know more about conditional variation, see the section Conditional Validation in this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I'd just like to mention that for it to work on the client-side, one should also write a conditional, JavaScript function and put it in the whenClient property. In my project, it looks like this:

              'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                    return value.split('.').pop() === 'txt';
                }",

Comment: More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$whenClient-detail)